# Doble foreign key en Entity Framework Net Core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor, net

estoy diseñando una base de datos y me veo en un problema a la hora de relacionar dos tablas .

La primera tabla se llama Paises y la segunda se llama Importaciones, en la tabla importaciones tengo una columna que se llama PaisOrigenID pero tambien tengo otra columna que se llama PaisProcedenciaID, cómo se haria para que ambas columnas tengan un foringkey apuntando a la tabla Paises?

Intenté esto pero no funcionó.

```
public class Importaciones
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int Cantidad { get; set; }

    public int PaisOrigenID { get; set; }
    public int PaisProcedenciaID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PaisOrigenID,PaisProcedenciaID")]
    public Paises Paises { get; set; }
}

/// TABLA PAISES
public class Paises
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Me aparece el siguiente error al querer agregarlo a una migración

```
The relationship from 'PermisosIndustrial.Paises' to 'Paises' with foreign key properties {'PaisOrigenID' : int, 'PaisDestinoID' : int} cannot target the primary key {'ID' : int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de seguir buscando he encontrado la solución en el siguiente enlace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559043/entity-framework-code-first-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer te falta definir la propiedad publica virtual del `modelo` de `Paises` relacionado

Ejemplo:

```
public int PaisOrigenID { get; set; }
public int PaisProcedenciaID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("PaisOrigenID,PaisProcedenciaID")]
public virtual Paises Paises { get; set; }
```

otra forma

```
[ForeignKey("Paises")]
public int PaisOrigenID { get; set; } 
public virtual Paises Paises { get; set; }
```

Comment: No, tampoco funciona, sigue apareciendo el mismo error :(